# «Тогда бы он дурно поступил(,) и я бы не жалела его»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Из "Анны Карениной".
[Варенька рассказывает, как ее бросил жених, потому что его мать не хотела, чтобы он женился на ней. Кити тоже бросил жених, но не из-за обстоятельств, а потому что влюбился в другую. В цитате ниже Кити говорит первая.]

> — Скажите, неужели не оскорбительно думать, что человек пренебрег вашею любовью, что он не хотел?..
>    — Да он не пренебрег; я верю, что он любил меня, но он был покорный сын...
>    — Да, но если б он не по воле матери, а просто, сам?.. — говорила Кити, чувствуя, что она выдала свою тайну и что лицо ее, горящее румянцем стыда, уже изобличило ее.
>    — Тогда бы он дурно **поступил, и я бы** не жалела его, — отвечала Варенька, очевидно поняв, что дело идет уже не о ней, а о Кити.

Почему в отмеченном месте стоит запятая? Разве оба предложения не относятся к "тогда"? Можно ли убрать запятую?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В этом сложном предложении второе простое предложение является следствием первого.
*Я бы не жалела его* (почему? по какой причине?) — *он дурно поступил*. То есть, на мой взгляд, эти простые предложения не являются однородными и относящимися к общему члену "тогда".

Comment: Мне видится "и я бы не жалела его" присоединительным предложением, это как бы совет Кити (я бы на твоём месте не жалела его)

Comment: @Людмила Но ведь жалеет его (оправдывает тем, что он покорный сын) Варенька.

Comment: Но ведь Варенька поняла, что дело идет уже не о ней, а о Кити, а там ситуация другая. Кити ведь и вопрос задаёт, чтобы понять, как ей отнестись к поступку  Вронского, он же оскорбил её ухаживанием за Анной.

Comment: @Людмила, спасибо за разъяснение тонкостей.